# mismatch assembly definition error after dll renaming on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

I made some enhancements to the web site in Visual Studio 2012 and rebuilt the project.  Up on the IIS server, I renamed the original dll to foo**OLD**.dll and copied up the newer version, foo.dll.

But now when I try to run the main page, there's an error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'foo**OLD**' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

I have tried stopping and starting the IIS  server, to no avail.

Apparently, IIS noticed my renaming of the file and has "remembered" it somewhere.  How do I tell IIS that I'm trying to replace the old dll with a newer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do iisreset
2. Go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files or
        C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
   Note: Select path based on framework version you are using.
3. Delete folder named after your application.

IIS will use newly copied file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the old DLL from the bin directory.

If you don't, you have two assemblies in that directory with the [same AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The runtime does not consider the file name when determining an assembly's identity. The assembly identity, which consists of the assembly name, version, culture, and strong name, must be clear to the runtime.

Now apparently the wrong one is loaded first, causing the error to be thrown, because the loading assembly (your site) is compiled against a newer version of the referenced assembly.